# dot slash vs nothing. What is the difference and what's better to use?

Tags: php, html, css, hyperlink, dir

Just for curiosity.

What is the better method to use and what is the difference between them ?

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="./css/css.css">
```

vs

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="css/css.css">
```

Comment: In my opinion first one is better, because in some scenarios for e.g., when you are making an iOS build using phone gap the second one might not work..

Comment: It's better to use absolute paths to your resources, and better names for your CSS files. For example, `/users/joe` could use `/css/users.css`. Then there is no worry about moving pages around and having relative links to assets break.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a relative URI, there is no difference between them.

Going without the `./` will save you 2 bytes, so it is **marginally** better.

---

In a UNIX style shell, leaving the `./` off will search `$PATH` while including it will search the current directory. Some people might be including the `./` out of habit from working on the shell.

Comment: So basically I can ask what's faster to use ? (save 2 bytes vs the time in ms to look for the $PATH) ?

Comment: @user3447293 — "the time in ms to look for the $PATH" I said *In a UNIX style shell*. URIs in a web browser are not in a UNIX style shell.

Comment: but the browser doesnt use $PATH

Comment: Let me ask it in a different version : href="css/css.css" saves 2 bytes and seems to be the better option but what is the disadvantage ? If there is no disadvantage can we say that it's better to use ?

Comment: There is no disadvantage. If there was, I would have mentioned it in the answer. I said it is better in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

ultimately, there is no difference. They both produce the same link to the same file.

As Quentin just said, it saves you 2 bytes in storage, but I suppose even that doesn't really make a difference.

It just somes down to personal preference/coding style. I never use the ./, never found the use for it. However, people from linux might prefer it, since there it is used to indicate the current directory a lot.